# About tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement the Grad-cam in R. And I met this error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.
```

I found some solutions online but they all use python. I was wondering how can we fix this problem in R version of keras. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can help

```
tf$compat$v1$disable_eager_execution()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.